# Consuming XML web services with powershell

Tags: xml, web-services, powershell

I have a few internal web services that I need to check periodically and Im trying to write a powershell script for them.
Im on powershell 2.0 so I cannot use 'invoke-webrequest', Im limited to "New-WebServiceProxy" or doing some magic.
I tried the examples in here and similar pages:
http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2009/05/15/powershell-v2-get-weather-function-using-a-web-service.aspx

Im new at web services and powershell so Im learning via examples.
All those have very well formatted WSDL that present XML structure etc.
They expose the methods and the parameters the methods take.

My internal web services are not like that,, they have schemasLocation, and something that look like 'multilevel relationships' , for example, on my WSDL I get the interesting method with:

```
$proxy | get member
```

then I try to get the method's overloads with the formula

```
$proxy.InterestingMethod
```

All I get is something like this:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1com_ABCWS_Service_wsdl.DBResponse getDB(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1com_ABCWS_Service_wsdl.DBRequest DBRequest)
```

I was expecting the list of the parameters I have to send!
I dont find reference to the 'DBRequest' on the WSDL,, I see them on the Schema,, on another URL,, and they seem to have the login, password, name, address, etc on different elements, on multiple levels,, so I dont know how to construct the request sending those parameters.

At this point I dont know if I can use the NewWebservice proxy on powershell.
I wonder if this can still be done,, or I need to learn how to consume the webservices 'raw', withouth the Newwebservice Proxy CMDLET and handle the XML by myself (obviously, a lot mroe complicated)
Am I doing this right? or I need to somehow consider the schema URL on this?

Thanks guys.
Dotty

-- 
Im adding additional details today July 25th.
Could be, but Im not sure how to send the parameter with the array inside (im reading today a book on powershell, it might help me too),, for example,, in the WSDL, the method is presented like this:

```
'<message name="getDB"><part name="request" element="ns1:DBRequest"/></message><message name="getDBResponse"><part name="response" element="ns2:DBResponse"/></message>'
```

that WSDL has reference to two schemas, if I open them using Firefox, on one I see the request method , like this

```
'<xs:element name="DBRequest"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="credentials" type="ns1:Credentials" form="qualified"/><xs:element name="Params" type="ns1:Params" form="qualified"/><xs:element name="Info" type="ns1:Info" form="qualified"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element><xs:element name="DBResponse"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="transactionResponse" type="ns1:TransactionResponse" form="qualified"/><xs:element name="extremeResponse" type="ns1:extremeResponse" form="qualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/><xs:element name="expressResponse" type="ns1:expressResponse" form="qualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema>'
```

and on the other, I see references to details of the parameters I have to send, like this:

'xs:complexType name="Credentials">'

and like this

```
'<xs:complexType name="Params"><xs:sequence><xs:element name="age" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="cType" type="tns:CTypeEnum"/><xs:element name="Method" type="xs:string"/><xs:element name="sType" type="tns:sTypeEnum"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType>'
```

See what I mean? the WSDL dont show me the parameters (or arguments) that I have to pass on,, they are inside the schema,, and because of that, I cannot figure out how to construct the request.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error do you try :

```
$proxy.getDB("Your database request")
```

Comment: Actually the name 'DB' is a coincidence, it is not a DB query,, but a method thats supposed to take about 6 parameters, most of them strings, and a couple on 'integer').
I tried sending the parameters, like this:
$proxy.getDB("login", "password", "param3", "param4", "param5", "param6")  but I get:
    Cannot find an overload for "getDB" and the argument count: "6".

Comment: According to the message you got, getDB just take one parameter, Perhaps your parameter are in a array ?

Comment: Hi JP I though the same,, that it is an array or something like that but I dont know how to use it,, I wrote additional details above regarding that, (space is reduce here on the answer box)